# How do I dynamically access property accessors in javascript?

Tags: javascript, properties, accessor

How do I dynamically access Property accessors in javascript? Lets say i'm building a linked list. Lets say this list can be any length and it changes dynamically.

```
var answerList = new ListNode(4);
answerList.next = new ListNode(5);
answerList.next.next = new ListNode(6);
answerList.next.next.next = new ListNode(7);
```

How can I make this go to the 100th .next without doing:

```
answerList.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to insert 100 elements in a LinkedList do

```
var head = new ListNode(0);
var temp = head; // sets temp to head 
for(let i=1; i<100;i++){
     temp.next = new ListNode(i); // links new nodes to temp
     temp = temp.next;} // at the end head->0->1->2..->98->99
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks man. I didn't realize you could link it through temp like that.

Comment: Do you mind if you accept this as the answer Anon?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using recursion if you pass `currLevel` and `finalLevel` as:

```
function getValue(linkedList, currLevel, finalLevel) {
  if (currLevel === finalLevel) return linkedList?.value;
  return getValue(linkedList.next, currLevel + 1, finalLevel);
}
```

You have to handle the case where the is not so many node that you passing a number then It could be possible that there won't be `.next` property on it i.e. means that is the last element in the linked list. one such way is as:

```
return (linkedList.next && getValue(linkedList.next, currLevel + 1, finalLevel));
```

```js
class ListNode {
  constructor(val) {
    this.value = val;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

var answerList = new ListNode(4);
answerList.next = new ListNode(5);
answerList.next.next = new ListNode(6);
answerList.next.next.next = new ListNode(7);

function getValue(linkedList, currLevel, finalLevel) {
  if (currLevel === finalLevel) return linkedList?.value;
  return getValue(linkedList.next, currLevel + 1, finalLevel);
}

console.log(getValue(answerList, 0, 3));
```